Google books API giving a 401 error that makes no sense to me
I must mention all of this was working perfectly and then stopped working suddenly. I was using a python script to upload epub files from my google drive to my google playbooks library.
This is my python script for Oauth2.0 flow to get token:
from flask import Flask, request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import json
import os


def credentials_to_dict(credentials):
    return {
        "token": credentials.token,
        "refresh_token": credentials.refresh_token,
        "token_uri": credentials.token_uri,
        "client_id": credentials.client_id,
        "client_secret": credentials.client_secret,
        "scopes": credentials.scopes,
        "expiry": credentials.expiry.isoformat() if credentials.expiry else None,
    }

flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    "client_secrets.json", scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/books"]
)

flow.redirect_uri = "https://callback/callback"

authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
    access_type="offline",
    include_granted_scopes="true",
    prompt="consent",
)

print("Please go to this URL:", authorization_url)


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/callback")
def callback():
    code = request.args.get("code")

    flow.fetch_token(code=code)
    creds = flow.credentials

    cred_dict = credentials_to_dict(creds)

    with open("credentials.json", "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(cred_dict, outfile)

    return "Authentication successful!"

app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)


The credentials.json file looks something like this:
{
    "token": "ya29.a0AcM612xFMQgQrX-jI1meqxyi2jZrTjiGN0rFiHQWq_Dg9hf7JKJXrtrb5gjCAZieeRxSZ-6k-X4a_qvZBF4rRGW4GQO2ksBkDobvMfbcBmem_zfHS_fN6I83Hf1naCgYKAWYSARESFQHGX2MihDmMJS1g7doDnZTdFV7iKg0175",
    "refresh_token": "1//09DwiJZIARAAGAkSNwF-L9VjT8t8aqhQIZ65Gl1Ga68C03ZB-M7Jz4Z5x3OB-ONj_YPc_pMVU8mI_i9g",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "client_id": "726229-jsq22ptgsjv4umdkf0sg0tljc.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "client_secret": "GOCSPX-CLuI2JI0_n0gU",
    "scopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/books"
    ],
    "expiry": "2024-08-21T16:57:53.932878"
}


Then I use the credentails to upload the file like this:
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import google.auth.transport.requests as refresh
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
import sys

id=sys.argv[1]

def upload_epub_to_play_books():
    # Load the OAuth 2.0 credentials from a file
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('/home/varo/scripts/playbooks/credentials.json')

    if not creds.valid:
        if creds.refresh_token:
            request = refresh.Request()
            creds.refresh(request)

        if creds.valid:
            print("Creds valid and were refreshed")
            with open('/home/varo/scripts/playbooks/credentials.json', 'w') as token:
                token.write(creds.to_json())
    else:
        print("creds already valid")

    # Create a Google Play Books API service client
    service = build('books', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Upload the epub file to Google Play Books
    response = service.cloudloading().addBook(drive_document_id=id).execute()
    print(response)


# Upload an epub file to Google Play Books
upload_epub_to_play_books()

This is the output:
This is the id: 1gODrE4DeRzmiwjrE3XTc-J8tToJ7Lh2F
Creds valid and were refreshed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/varo/scripts/playbooks/add_to_playbooks.py", line 33, in <module>
    upload_epub_to_play_books()
  File "/home/varo/scripts/playbooks/add_to_playbooks.py", line 28, in upload_epub_to_play_books
    response = service.cloudloading().addBook(drive_document_id=id).execute()
  File "/home/varo/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/varo/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 938, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://books.googleapis.com/books/v1/cloudloading/addBook?drive_document_id=1gODrE4DeRzmiwjrE3XTc-J8tToJ7Lh2F&alt=json returned "Invalid Credentials". Details: "[{'message': 'Invalid Credentials', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'authError', 'location': 'Authorization', 'locationType': 'header'}]">

I am not for the life of me able to figure this out. I have tried re-authenticating and obtaining a new token but nothing seems to work. Please help!

Do you understand the ramifications of posting your credentials.json file on a public forum?  I strongly suggest you go create a new secrete key on that client

Don't worry, it's redacted. Just looks like it's the real deal
